# How to change partition size for ubuntu on dual boot os?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a pc with **win7** . Along with **win7** i wanted to install ubuntu also.
While i was installing **Ubuntu12.04** I have given 5GB partition for that.
Now I want to extend **5GB to 20GB** . 
I don't have any idea, how to go?
Anybody's help would be appreciated.

Comment: By memory do you mean disk space?

Comment: Yes, I mean disk space only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice easy way would be to use GParted, find a full guide here: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2036-how-to-resize-a-partition-using-gparted-on-linux

Make backups first though. And be careful with your MBR.

Comment: I have installed Gparted . but I have confusion about /Dev/hda1  and /Dev/hda2 where i select memory?

Comment: boot into ubuntu, and execute the `df -h` command. That will tell you what devices are mounted, and where to. You are looking for which device is mounted on `/`, chances are the other one is a swap partition, or the windows partition.